# Regex for IP Address using unobtrusive data- attributes

Tags: regex, validation

I am using the following regex pattern with jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

I put the regex expression into the
data-val-regex-pattern
attribute of the input element

```
\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b
```

this works for `127.0.0.1` but doesn't work for `192.168.2.91`

I realize I could add a custom rule, but need to use the data-attribute with the built-in regex rule.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for that, because the regex pattern matches both IPs (http://regexr.com/3cec7).

Comment: Doesn't `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` work?

Comment: I think the regex will work, I think something is wrong with the special characters.  for instance the \\.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that $.ajax was appending the Razor generated HTML into the dom and was adding extra \ character so \b was turning into \\b